# Objective-c method to use blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that calls a long running process. the long running process and I use AFNetworking which itself uses blocks and returns success block and failure block.  So I am trying to test my method and the tests will fail before the success block is called.  I thought I would try to get my method to also use blocks.  I have another method that I managed to change to use blocks but that only uses bool isFinished and the return value is void.  The method I have difficult with needs to return NSDecimalNumber* and takes an NSString.

Method signature

- (NSDecimalNumber*) getRate:(NSString*) rateCode;

I would like to be able to able to add a completion block with a BOOL that I set when the AFNetworking method enters the success block

I would also like to be able to call the method and within it's completion block access the NSDecimalNumber* value it returned

Possible?  If so please show me how

Comment: This could help http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

Comment: Don't prefix methods with "get".

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to split it apart.

You can have a `fetchRate:` method that takes a completion block:

```
- (void)fetchRate:(NSString*)rateCode completion:(void (^)(NSDecimalNumber *))completion;
```

Then call like this:

```
void (^completion)(NSDecimalNumber *) = ^(NSDecimalNumber * rate){
    // this is called when rate is returned from your webservice
}

// call fetchRate: now, results will arrive later...
[ myObj fetchRate:<rate code> completion:completion ];

// code here runs immediately; the results come back later.
```

`-fetchRate:` looks something like...

```
- (void)fetchRate:(NSString *)rateCode completion:(void (^)(NSDecimalNumber *))completion
{
    void (^asiCompletionBlock)(/*args*/) = ^(/*...args...*/){
        // called after ASI request completes

        NSDecimalNumber * answer = /* get answer from ASI HTTP response */

        // call our completion block that was passed in:
        completion( answer );
    };

    // do your asi HTTP request here, pass asiCompletionBlock for completion arg
}
```

Comment: ...and call it "fetchRate" or something like that, [not "**get**Rate"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html).

Comment: [CurrencyConverter fetchRate:key completion:<#^(NSDecimalNumber *)rateCompletionBlock#>{
     
    }];

compiler complains of syntax

Comment: fetchRate header

+ (void) fetchRate:(NSString*)rateCode completion:(void (^)(NSDecimalNumber *)) rateCompletionBlock;

Comment: is it a class method or an instance method? You are right--I left out the parameter name in my example.

Comment: it is a class method